# Subsequences related with square table

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences

Let $m\geqslant1$ be a fixed integer.

Let  $f(n)$ be [A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814), the exponent of the highest power of $2$ dividing $n$, a.k.a. the binary carry sequence, the ruler sequence, or the $2$-adic valuation of $n$.

Let $g(n)$ be [A025480](https://oeis.org/A025480), $g(2n) = n$, $g(2n+1) = g(n)$.

Then we have an integer sequences given by
\begin{align}
a(0)&=1\\
a(n)& = a\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+a\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n-2^{f(n)}}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+ma(g(n-1))
\end{align}
I conjecture that
$$a(2^{k-1}-1)=T(m,k), T(m,0)=1$$
where $T(n,k)$ is [A111528](https://oeis.org/A111528), square table, read by antidiagonals, where the g.f. for row $n+1$ is generated by:
$$xR_{n+1}(x) = \frac{1+nx - \frac{1}{R_n(x)}}{n+1}$$
with
$$R_0(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}n!x^n$$
Is there a way to prove it?